# What variations of imports allow an exe to connect to the internet?

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, exe, dllimport

EXE and DLL files usually come with lots of imports, some of them point to files located in System32 (Win APIs) and some of them point to files in the current directory. At some point an application likes to check for updates online, send feedback from customers and send crash reports to app developers so the application needs to initialize internet communications.

I have searched the [WinAPI docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/Wininet/nf-wininet-internetopena) and found out that the `InternetOpenA` export in `wininet.dll` initializes communications through the internet, but....I did some testing and found out that it is not always true. Some applications can still connect to the internet without `wininet.dll` listed as an import.

How is that possible? Do those applications come with their own DLLs to connect to the internet, resulting in not being dependent on wininet.dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous HTTP(S) stacks in the Windows API and plenty of open-source and private stacks.

For the vast majority of these implementations of HTTP client libraries, they all need access to the TCP/IP stack in Windows, and the primary interface for that is the [Winsock2 stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-start-page-2) (ws2_32.dll).

HTTPS Stacks in Windows that build on top of Winsock include the following:

- [WinInet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/about-wininet)
- [WinHttp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/about-winhttp)
- [URLMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85))
- [BITS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bits/background-intelligent-transfer-service-portal)

Some other 3rd party implementations built on top of Winsock include:

- [libCurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/)
- [Boost Beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html)

Likely many others.

Also, many programming frameworks including .NET, Java, Python, etc... have their own socket and http libraries as well.

There is no requirement that an application must use any of these stacks - they can roll their own on top of the Windows socket library or theoretically thunk down to a lower part of the network stack.

Comment: Fixed URLs in links.

Comment: The vast majority of apps/libraries will ultimately get their networking access via either WinInet or Winsock directly. WinHTTP and URLMon are not common, and BITS is very rare (outside of system components), and custom stacks are almost unheard of nowadays once Microsoft standardized its Winsock implementation around Windows 9x (earlier Windows versions didn't have a Winsock implementation provided by Microsoft).

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Ironically, we use all three of those stacks you cite as uncommon on my team's project.  WinHttp has the advantage that it can run in a service process and has a lot more flexibility that WinInet (API stinks, but it's flexible).  URLMon is old, I agree.  BITS is useful for when there's not a foreground expectation to complete the download (e.g. download an auto-update in background).  Do I like this - heck no.  It's the legacy code thing that piles up and you don't have any business need to fix what's not broken. :)